# How to get RSS feeds off a PHP file or convert PHP to xml

Tags: php, jquery, rss

I created an RSS feed page with PHP and tried to run it through through a JavaScript RSS reader code (http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/ )

It does not recognize the PHP file as having XML code. Though I copied the rendered code generated from PHP and added it in an XML file and it worked.

Is there a way to change this PHP file extension into an XML? Or make the PHP file visible to the above JavaScript code?

I tried using the .htaccess to change the file type (as there are tutorials all over covering that) but it did not work.

Can you recommend anything?

This is my code:

```
<?php
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");  
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; ++$i) {
    $track = $xml->addChild('track');
    $track->addChild('path', "song$i.mp3");
    $track->addChild('title', "Track $i - Track Title");
}

print($xml->asXML());

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some environments do not manage files based on mime-types but just rely on the extension of the filename. I would change two things:

- You can try to force the filename to have .xml / .rss extension.
- Do not use 'xml' as a node name. Change it to 'playlist' or some other thing.

So, the code could be something like this:

```
<?php
header ("Content-Type: text/xml");
$filename = 'playlist.rss';
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<playlist/>');
... // The rest of the code keeps as the original
?>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. with your code it works to look at here it is: http://aurelkurtula.co.uk/rss.php but it does not load here: http://aurelkurtula.co.uk/zrssfeed-114/example.html - i tried linking to the feed with ../rss.php and ../playlist.php but it does not get the data. do you know why. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

the `Content-Type` header should by `text/xml`

Your XML should also adhere to RSS standards http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification which it probably is doing since you can successfully open it when php is not rendering it.

Comment: I updated the that I am using. is the header correct? - thanks for your help